# asp.net mvc jquery paging plugin

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

can some lead me to best jquery asp.net mvc paging plugin ?

can some one tell me that http://tablesorter.com/docs/index.html  paging plugin in there can be intergrated with asp.net mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some useful links for paging are
http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/20/simplepager---jquery-paging-plugin--updated
http://www.trirand.com/blog/
http://rikrikrik.com/jquery/pager/